# Create Conditionally Incrementing Value - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table with a list of consecutive dates. The table also has a Day Type field consisting: Business Day (B), Saturday (X), Sunday (Y) & Holiday(H)

I want to add an additional column which has an incrementing number.
The number should only increment if:

- It is the first day in the list and it is a business day.
- The previous day was a business day.

Desired Result:

```
DATE         DAY_TYPE   NUMBER
2017-03-09   B          1
2017-03-10   B          2
2017-03-11   X          3
2017-03-12   Y          3
2017-03-13   H          3
2017-03-14   B          3
2017-03-15   B          4
2017-03-16   H          5
2017-03-17   B          5
```

Comment: So what have you tried so far, and what problems did you have with it?

Comment: Perhaps a recursive CTE?

Comment: can u share ur effor.. its simply the logic you need to implement .case when then .. statement while inserting the values .

Comment: I really am unsure how to tackle this. Have thought about a while with an embedded case, but can't seem to come up with a logical way to get it working.  Sorry not an overly experienced SQL user, mostly self taught off this site !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using a recursive [common table expression](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx)

```
DECLARE @sample TABLE ( [date] DATE, day_type CHAR(1))
INSERT @sample
( [date], day_type )
VALUES
('2017-03-09','B')
,('2017-03-10','B')
,('2017-03-11','X')
,('2017-03-12','Y')
,('2017-03-13','H')
,('2017-03-14','B')
,('2017-03-15','B')
,('2017-03-16','H')
,('2017-03-17','B')

;WITH cteSample
AS(
SELECT
      ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY [S].[date]) 'RN'
    , S.[date]
    , S.day_type
FROM @sample S
),cteRecursive
AS(
    SELECT
        b.RN, b.[date], b.day_type, 1 'Number'
    FROM
        cteSample b
    WHERE
        b.RN = 1 AND b.day_type = 'B'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
         e.RN, e.[date], e.day_type
        ,CASE WHEN ( e.day_type IN ('B') AND r.day_type IN ('B') OR e.day_type NOT IN ('B') AND r.day_type IN ('B') )
             THEN r.Number + 1 ELSE r.Number END
    FROM
        cteSample  e
    INNER JOIN
        cteRecursive r ON e.RN = r.rn + 1
    )
SELECT * FROM cteRecursive
```

Comment: thanks @Cool_Br33ze, worked exactly as required as long as I added "OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);" after the final SELECT FROM statement.  Cheers